# How to connect to a SQL instance in an App Engine custom runtime Dockerfile?

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, dockerfile

There is a lot of documentation but not specific about Dockerfiles (or I missed it).

My app.yaml file:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
env_variables:
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project-name:europe-west1:test001;dbname=db001
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'qwerty'
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ARG dbuser
ENV dbuser ${MYSQL_USER}
ARG dbpass
ENV dbpass ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
ARG dbhost
ENV dbhost ${MYSQL_DSN}

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install mysql-client
RUN mysql -h ${dbhost} -u ${dbuser} -p${dbpass} -e "CREATE DATABASE 'test';"
```

Documentation followed:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#Node.js_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

Comment: what errors are you seeing ? Did you whitelist any ips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql` command line does not understand the DSN syntax you are passing. The socket and database must be passed in separately.

Additionally "RUN" entries in your Dockerfile are run when building the docker image, before it is actually ran in your App. As a result it doesn't have the environment available to it. Moreover you probably don't want to be configuring or accessing a remote database when building an image.

Here's an alternative:

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
env_variables:
  MYSQL_SOCK: /cloudsql/project-name:europe-west1:test001
  MYSQL_DB: db001
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'qwerty'
```

your_program.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -S $MYSQL_SOCK -u $MYSQL_DB -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DB -e "CREATE DATABASE 'test';"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install mysql-client
CMD ["your_program.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks David, I think it also has to do that my ENV vars seem to be empty. Do you know how I can pass them from the yaml file to the docker file?

Comment: The "RUN" commands in your Dockerfile are executed when building the docker image, not actually as part of your app. So the env variables in your app are not visible to them. It also doesn't make sense to run mysql commands to *build* the dockerfile... sounds like you may want it to run within your app. Try moving the mysql call to a separate shell script and using it as the CMD or ENTRYPOINT of your dockerfile.